# If the Minkowski sum of two convex closed sets is a Euclidean ball, then can the two sets be anything other than Euclidean balls?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

If for two convex closed sets $S_1$ and $S_2$, the Minkowski sum is a Euclidean ball then can $S_1$ and $S_2$ be anything other than Euclidean balls themselves. I suspect they can be but I haven't found a counterexample. I don't have experience with Minkowski sums so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Two notes (1) I suspect that by "sphere", you mean a solid sphere (one that contains its interior). Most mathematicians call that a "ball", and use "sphere" to mean just the boundary.

Comment: (2) You should specify that you are talking about convex closed sets (unless that's not what you want). I'm sure there are some stupid counter-examples otherwise by taking $S_1$ and $S_2$ to be dense subsets of balls, or deleting a small piece deep in the interior of a ball.

Comment: Subject to those notes: Nice question! Looking forward to the answer.

Comment: Oh right. I meant euclidean ball and convex closed sets. Edited

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is almost certainly false.  The following animation shows two convex shapes (with outlines shown in red and green) whose Minkowski sum is a disk of radius 3 (with outline shown in blue).  The green shape is an ellipse with major and minor radii 1 and 1/2, which uniquely determines the red shape.

[image]

I do not have a proof that the red shape is convex, but it shouldn't be too hard to check.

Incidentally, here is the Mathematica code I used to produce this animation:

`MyPlot = ParametricPlot[{3*{Cos[t], Sin[t]},
          With[{u = ArcTan[-Sin[t], Cos[t]/2]}, 
               3*{Sin[u], -Cos[u]} - {Cos[t], Sin[t]/2}]},
               {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
myframes = 
  Table[With[{u = ArcTan[-Sin[t], Cos[t]/2]}, 
    With[{pt = 3*{Sin[u], -Cos[u]} - {Cos[t], Sin[t]/2}}, 
     Show[MyPlot, 
      ParametricPlot[pt + {Cos[r], Sin[r]/2}, {r, 0, 2 Pi}, 
       PlotStyle -> Darker[Green]], 
      Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[pt]}]]]], {t, 0, 2 Pi - Pi/20,
     Pi/20}]; ListAnimate[myframes]`

**Edit:** Here is a simpler solution using two congruent shapes.  The boundary of each shape is the union of two circular arcs, each of which is congruent to 1/4 of the blue circle.

[image]

Comment: Jim, what software did you use to make the animation?

Comment: @Arjang It's just Mathematica.  If you make a list of frames (`myframes` in the code above), then you can use `Export` to save as an animated gif, e.g. `Export(filename, myframes)`.

Comment: Nicely done.  I wish I could give another +1.

Comment: As everyone else has been saying, nice answer!

Answer (score 19):

Here's mine.  Done before I saw Jim's solution (honest).  But after seeing his, I animated mine, too (using Maple).

Two copies of the Reuleaux triangle

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle

same size, one rotated by 180 degrees from the other.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For $\mu$ a Borel positive measure on the sphere $S^{n-1}$, consider a continuous Minkowski sum of segments
$$ K_\mu = \int_{S^{n-1}} [0,\theta] \, \mathrm{d}\mu (\theta) .$$
The set $K_\mu$ is convex (it could be defined by its support function, then the integral becomes a usual one). Now observe that (1) $K_{\mu+\nu} = K_\mu + K_\nu$ (2) by rotation invariance, $K_\mu$ is a Euclidean ball if $\mu$ is the uniform measure (3) there are many ways to write the uniform measure as a sum of positive measures.