# Conformal map from the punctured unit disc onto the unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis

I remember seeing this statement, I don't remember where (maybe in Lang's Complex). Is this true or do I have a faulty memory. It was always somewhere in the back of my mind but I never believed it. Is it true that there is a conformal map from the punctured unit disc onto the unit disc?

Comment: Is what true? You haven't made a statement, nor asked a comprehensible question.

Comment: Ok let me edit that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a *surjective* conformal map, though (in opposition to *bijective*, which is what Soarer has in mind in his answer). Just compose an holomorphic bijection from the disc to the upper half-plane with $z\mapsto e^{i z}$.

(I made a [video](http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~aldoc9/tmp/curves.swf) showing the images under the map $z\mapsto\exp\frac{z-1}{z+1}$, which is a surjection from the unit disk to the punctured unit disk, of the circles centered at $0$. You can see in it how it manages to avoid the origin.) (The file will not last forever in that location... if someone can upload it to some site or another, it would be great!)

**Later** In any case, this is the Mathematica code I used:

```
Animate[
 ParametricPlot[
   With[{z = r Exp[I theta]},
   Through[{Re, Im}[Exp[(z - 1)/(z + 1)]]]
   ],
  {theta, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
  PlotPoints -> 1000, Ticks -> False
  ],
 {r, 0, 0.999, 0.001}
 ]
```

[image: punctured disk map]

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I was looking for.

Comment: amazing video. thank you!

Comment: Technically this doesn't answer the actual question of whether there exists a surjection in the opposite direction...

Comment: @Vladimir: come to think about it, this is true. Mariano's example was so nice that I forgot about my original question :) I would even add that it hold even when the map is locally injective. I just can't represent it.

Comment: @Theo: I could not convince Mathematica to generate a reasonably sized animated GIF :(

Comment: :( But tanks for trying! Jim Belk managed to do it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42877/if-the-minkowski-sum-of-two-convex-closed-sets-is-a-euclidean-ball-then-can-the/42897#42897) (with source), but his thing is much smaller in size and probably much less complex (I think

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WXJLQ.gif) is my attempt (though I used an older version of *Mathematica*); would this be suitable?

Comment: @J.M.: great! Can you upload it and add a link to my answer?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, which I stumbled upon, but it seems to me that the answers currently address two questions. Often in complex analysis "conformal map" is used equivalently to "biholomorphic map", so let me avoid any confusion by using the terms "conformal isomorphism" and "locally conformal".

- There is no conformal isomorphism between the unit disc and the punctured disc, since one is simply-connected and the other is not. (Soarer's answer).
- There is a locally conformal map from a simply-connected domain (and hence from the disc) onto the punctured disc, namely the exponential map. Of course, this is true for any domain omitting at least two points, due to the uniformisation theorem.

However, neither answer addresses the original question as I understand it, namely: is there a locally conformal map from the punctured disc onto the unit disc.

We may instead ask: is there a locally conformal map $\phi$ from the unit disc $D$ onto itself that is not a conformal isomorphism? If such a map exists, let $z$ and $w$ be points with $\phi(z)=\phi(w)$, we may assume without loss of generality that $z=0$, and $\phi\colon D\setminus\{0\}\to D$ has the desired property.

Of course, by the Riemann mapping theorem, we can just look for a locally conformal map from a simply-connected domain $U$ onto another simply-connected domain $V$. To see that such a map exists is a nice exercise. You should imagine drawing a simply-connected domain on a three-sheeted cover of the plane (with two different branch points) whose projection to the plane is simply-connected.

I believe that this cover can be realised by a cubic polynomial $p$ with two critical points. That is, there is a simply-connected domain $V$ containing neither critical point such that $p\colon V\to p(V)$ is not injective, and $p(V)$ is simply-connected.

Answer (score 2):

No, because punctured disc is not simply connected.

Comment: Could you say more (why do holomorphic functions preserve the property of being simply-connected?)

Comment: I think what Soarer had in mind was to apply the Riemann mapping Theorem, but it does not apply in my case.

Comment: I had in mind a bijective conformal map, which is just a biholomorphism. Sorry for the confusion.